# Python string format from current namespace

Tags: python

I find myself writing a lot of stuff like this:

```
s = "{v1}_{v2}_{v3}_{v4}_{v5}".format(v1="foo", v2=v2, v3=v3, v4=v4, v5=v5)
```

Is it possible to make Python's `string.format` to use variables from the current namespace? The above call could then be simplified to:

```
s = "{v1}_{v2}_{v3}_{v4}_{v5}".format(v1="foo")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Were you thinking of something like this?

```
>>> v1 = "foo"
>>> v2,v3,v4,v5 = 1,2,3,4
>>> s = "{v1}_{v2}_{v3}_{v4}_{v5}".format(v1="foo", v2=v2, v3=v3, v4=v4, v5=v5)
>>> s
'foo_1_2_3_4'
>>> s = "{v1}_{v2}_{v3}_{v4}_{v5}".format(**locals())
>>> s
'foo_1_2_3_4'
```

For the record, though, I'd avoid doing this.  If the variables are the same kinds of thing then they should be together in some structure, from which the values could be obtained without using `locals()`.  Even if they're not, I think I'd prefer to pull them together into a separate dict manually and then use that before using `locals()` this way.

[*Ed: You're such a hypocrite. You use `string.Template` and `locals()` this way all the time to generate suites of parameter files for simulations.  Don't pretend that you don't.*

Me: Yeah, but I don't want to encourage other people to pick up my bad habits.

*Ed: at the least you should admit that you find it useful, if you're going to be pretend to be some more-explicit-than-thou coder.*

Me: ...]

Comment: I use "**vars()" instead of "**locals()" to save keystrokes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new feature in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) that gives this ability directly:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
'He said his name is Fred.'
```